# AJAX Request For Like Link Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I'm working on a like system with PDO, PHP and AJAX.
But, its not working.

Here's the PHP Code.

```
                    $get_likes_sql = "SELECT * FROM `likes` WHERE post_id=:post_id AND liker_id=:my_id";
                    $get_likes = $db->prepare($get_likes_sql);
                    $get_likes->execute(array(
                    ":post_id" => $post_id,
                    ":my_id" => $my_id
                    ));
                    $likes_numrows = $get_likes->rowCount();
                    if ($likes_numrows == 0) {
                        echo "<a class='like-link' id='$post_id' title='Like'>Like</a>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<a class='like-link' id='$post_id' title='Unlike'>Unlike</a>";
                    }
```

Here's the AJAX script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.like-link', function(){
    if($(this).attr('title')=='Like'){
      $.post('ajax.like.php',{pid:$(this).attr('id'),action:'like'},function(){
        $(this).text('Unlike');
        $(this).attr('title','Unlike');
     });
  }else{
     if($(this).attr('title')=='Unlike'){
        $.post('ajax.like.php',{pid:$(this).attr('id'),action:'unlike'},function(){
          $(this).text('Like');
          $(this).attr('title','Like');
          });
       }
    }
});
});
```

The Problem is that nothing happens after clicking on like link neither on unlike link.

Comment: ajax.like.php Whether this is a correct file name?

Comment: While `rowCount()` appears to work for you.  It is not good code.  `rowCount()` is for UPDATE,DELETE,and INSERT primarily: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php.  You should be running a `SELECT count(*)` especially considering you aren't using any of the data from the query.

Comment: @IndraKumarS Sorry..
Yeah It Is The Correct Filename

Answer (score 1):

This is where debugging comes into place. First off, let's see if the AJAX call succeeds. Put in `console.log('foo');` statements, with different strings to trace what the JavaScript code does. If the AJAX call is being made, you should be able to see it in the debugger as well.

After that, you should be able to see the results going into the PHP script. You can dump the variables at the top `var_dump($_POST);exit;`.

There should also be some code where the `$_POST` variable is linked to `$post_id` and `$my_id`.

Since this isn't the complete code example, I can only help you this much. Please let us know if you managed to debug it. Else the complete code example would be nice for us to help you out some more.

Answer (score -1):

use Console.log function to see which part of your code is executed and which is not